# Joining results from 3 tables with same date

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables like this:

table1

```
ID  Date        Number   City
--------------------------------
1   18.11.2019  345      Bristol
```

table2

```
ID  Date        Type       Code
-------------------------------
3   18.11.2019  returned   11
```

table3

```
ID  Date        Source    Product
----------------------------------
39  18.11.2019  unknown   shirt
```

I would like to write a query that shows a result for the same date on all three tables.

Desired result:

```
Date        table1_Number   table1_City  table2_Type   table2_Code  table3_Source  table3_Product
18.11.2019  345             Bristol      returned      11           unknown        shirt
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. SO isn't a free service code. We can help you but you have to provide us what you have tried. I'll suggest to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: join on Date doesn't work?

Comment: "I would like" is not a question, or even a description of a problem. What have you researched? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Hint: have you attempted to use INNER JOIN for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for simple joins, as follows?

```
select 
    t1.number  table1_number,
    t1.city    table1_city,
    t2.type    table2_type,
    t2.code    table2_code,
    t3.source  table3_source,
    t3.product table3_product
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.date = t.date
inner join table3 t3 on t3.date = t.date
```